# Issue after remove (#) hashbangs from routing in angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have remove (#) hashbangs by `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` in ui-route.
and set `<base href="/public/">`

when I have tried to `localhost:59940/public/#/home` url # is remove and url look `localhost:59940/public/home` and getting home view.

but when I have tried `localhost:59940/public/home` url. I have getting 404 Not Found error.

help me for getting home view when try to access `localhost:59940/public/home` in browser.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the browser resolves urls before your angular app responds, and indeed the resource for that route is not there. The solution I have used is to make your 404 route return the index.html page and use ui-router to handle real 404 cases. But another idea is to match all of the client routes to routes on your server which return the index.html.

Answer (score 1):

To enable `$locationProvider.html5Mode` in angular, you also need to some side server changes.

Other then your static assets and apis path, all other routes should server `index.html`(your main SPA page) only.

See below code. 
This is how you can do it in node.js using express server.

```js
var app = require('express')();

app.configure(function() {

  // Static files - all js, css, images, etc go into the static path
  app.use('/static', express.static('/static'));

  // If a static file is invalid so we send 404
  app.use('/static', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send(404);
  });

  // This route deals enables HTML5Mode by forwarding missing files to the index.html
  app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
  });

});

app.listen(3000);
```